# Debugging Go Code with GDB. Go extension "Invalid data type for function to be called."

Tags: go, gdb

Using GDB with golang is an exciting thing~~
Base on the [document](https://golang.org/doc/gdb), Go Extensions was provided. It can print the length of maps,string and slice.

However, when I executed "p $len(var)", I got an error "Invalid data type for function to be called". I am sure that the type of var is map.

Maybe, not many people pay attention to this problem? Or, should I ask this quesion in Go's forum?